# Hidden file with Setup Wizard installation

Tags: c#, wpf, installation

I am developing a wpf c # application with the management of a license.
when the client obtains his license, the application allows him to import it with an 'OpenFileDialog', this license file is an XML (License.xml). When importing this file, it is copying in 'ExecutablePath'

```
            openFileDialog.ShowDialog();
        string filePath = openFileDialog.FileName.Trim();
        if (filePath != string.Empty)
        {
            string filename = Path.GetFileName(filePath);
            if (filename.ToUpper() == "LICENCE.XML")
            {
                if (!ReadLicense(filePath))
                {
                    return false;
                }
                else
                {
                    string destPath = Path.GetDirectoryName(System.Windows.Forms.Application.ExecutablePath);
                    File.Copy(filePath, Path.Combine(destPath, filename), true);
                    return true;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
```

The application restarts and recognizes it.

```
    if (GetLicenceFile())
{
    App.Current.Shutdown();
    System.Windows.Forms.Application.Restart();
}
```

In DEBUG mode, this file is copied correctly and is visible in the 'C: \ Program Files (x86) \ AppName' folder. If I copy the release folder in 'C: \ Program Files (x86) ..' it works fine too.

The application is installed by a Setup Wizard, when the application starts, it claims the license, and after the import, it recognizes it and starts, everything works fine. 
What is questioning me is that the license file (License.xml) is not visible in the installation folder ('C: \ Program Files (x86) \ AppName'), yet it finds it correctly. I put sniffers to watch like this:

```
File.AppendAllText(@"G:\Sniffers\path.txt", destPath + " : Licence path\n");
```

If I uninstall the application from Control Panel, 'C: \ Program Files (x86) \ AppName' disappears completely, but at the next installation, the application starts by finding the license, while the file that is supposed to be in 'C: \ Program Files (x86) \ AppName' is supposed to be removed on uninstallation.

We might think that 'License.xml' is copying elsewhere.

I do not understand why I can not find this file with Wizard Installation, even the Windows Explorer search does not find it even with the hidden file options.

A idea?

Comment: You realise snce win7 most users can't write to program files?

Comment: No i know that, and i set 'Full access' for user, but maybe I'm wrong... :( Then, where is this file?

Comment: I just changed the destination of the file to ProgramData and it works fine.
I am sorry for this ignorance, thank you Andy. But for my culture, could you tell me where was the copy file because the application found it well !!

Comment: You can't write to ProgramData either.  A broken manifest is a possible explanation, missing the trustInfo element.  You'll then be treated like a legacy XP program that doesn't know anything about UAC yet, these files are redirected to isolated storage.

Comment: More on UAC file virtualization can be found from http://techgenix.com/protecting-system-files-uac-virtualization-part1/ Most developers learned that during Windows XP->Vista upgrade, so you just just need to study that in 2019.

Comment: Thank you so much Lex Li, i'll work to write data et files in AppData Folder.